# Que puedo hacer para mostrar los datos de varios objetos ¿Los paso a un diccionario y luego a una lista?

Tags: python, lista, bucle-for, diccionarios, herencia

Estoy aprendiendo POO con Python. Me puse como proyecto crear un juego por consola.

He practicado los conceptos por separado como herencia, diccionario, listas, funciones, etc: Pensaba al principio crear un solo personaje genérico y que esté al proceso vaya incrementado sus estadísticas. Hacerlo está bien, me propuse un poco más desafiante. Importando un archivo 'personajes' donde tengo la clase Base Genérica. De ahí cree 3 clases más para el Usuario. Quiero mostrar la información de los PJ como prioridad (luego veré como seleccionar el pj)

Clase Base de PJ Generico:

```
class CharacterBase:
    def __init__(self, rol, nombre, vida, ataque, defensa, vivo, nivel):
        super(CharacterBase, self).__init__()
        self.rol = rol
        self.nombre = nombre
        self.vida = vida
        self.ataque = ataque
        self.defensa = defensa
        self.vivo = True
        self.nivel = nivel
```

1 de las 3 Clases jugable para el Usuario

```
class Arquero(CharacterBase):
    def __init__(self, rol, nombre, vida, ataque, defensa, vivo, nivel, energia, curacion, costeCuracion):
        super().__init__(rol, nombre, vida, ataque, defensa, vivo, nivel)
        self.energia = energia
        self.curacion = curacion
        self.costeCuracion = costeCuracion
        self.experiencia = 0
        self.oro = 25
        self.xpSiguienteNivel = 150
```

Codigo del main buscando las mil vueltas de como imprimir los personajes

```
listStatsPJ = []
#Personajes jugables
userArcher =  Arquero("Arquero", "Oriso", 230, 79, 62, True, 1, 150, 30, 25)
userWarrior = Guerrero("Guerrero", "Hugohin", 180, 75, 75, True, 1, 70, 25, 20)
userWizard =  Brujo("Brujo", "Kihiary", 250, 90, 35, True, 1, 170, 40, 50)

#listStatsPJ.append(Arquero("Arquero", "Oriso", 230, 79, 62, True, 1, 150, 30, 25))
#listStatsPJ.append(Guerrero("Guerrero", "Hugohin", 180, 75, 75, True, 1, 70, 25, 20))
#listStatsPJ.append(Brujo("Brujo", "Kihiary", 250, 90, 35, True, 1, 170, 40, 50))
clear_Screen()
print("Bienvenidos a este juego RPG por consola\n")

print("Debes seleccionar un personaje en la lista\n")
for i in range(len(listStatsPJ)):
    print(listStatsPJ[i], end=" ")
```

Pensaba hacer, intentare pasar los datos de los objetos personajes jugables a un diccionario, creando la llave y luego asignado los valores. Luego enviarlo todo a una lista e iterar la lista en bucle algo como for k, v in i.items(). Tal vez es mucho proceso y código basura, por ahora en mi campo de conocimientos. Es lo que puedo hacer ¿Está bien la idea? ¿Puedo ahorrarme este proceso con un fragmento de código más directo o menos engorroso?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Buen día,

Lo que normalmente se hace es utilizar los [métodos mágicos](https://geekflare.com/es/magic-methods-in-python/) de las clases para generar la representación visual de la misma.

Existen dos métodos mágicos para la representación visual de un objeto, `__str__` y `__repr__`. ([Lectura recomendada](https://www.analyticslane.com/2020/07/03/diferencias-entre-str-y-repr-en-python/)). Básicamente `__str__` muestra la forma legible de un objeto, es decir, la forma "linda" de representar el objeto, y `__repr__` muestra la forma escrita, o "cadena oficial" de un objeto.

El método mágico `__dir__`, por defecto incluye una lista de los atributos y métodos de un objeto, por lo que podríamos utilizarlo para imprimir todos los atributos del mismo.

Ejemplo de la implementación de `__str__` y `__repr__`:

```
class CharacterBase(object):
    def __init__(self, rol, nombre, vida, ataque, defensa, vivo, nivel):
        super(CharacterBase, self).__init__()
        self.rol = rol
        self.nombre = nombre
        self.vida = vida
        self.ataque = ataque
        self.defensa = defensa
        self.vivo = True
        self.nivel = nivel

    # Método mágico para la representación de una clase
    def __str__(self):
        # Obtener el nombre de la clase
        class_name = self.__class__.__name__
        # Obtener los atributos de la clase
        # Podemos agregar saltos de línea y espacios para imprimirlos de forma más organizada
        attributes = "\n    " + "\n    ".join([f"{attr} = {getattr(self, attr)!r}" for attr in self.__dict__])
        return f"{class_name}({attributes})"

    # Método mágico para la representación escrita del objeto
    def __repr__(self):
        # Obtener el nombre de la clase
        class_name = self.__class__.__name__
        # Obtener los atributos de la clase
        attributes = ', '.join([f'{attr}={getattr(self, attr)!r}' for attr in self.__dict__])
        return f"{class_name}({attributes})"


class Arquero(CharacterBase):
    def __init__(self, rol, nombre, vida, ataque, defensa, vivo, nivel, energia, curacion, costeCuracion):
        super().__init__(rol, nombre, vida, ataque, defensa, vivo, nivel)
        self.energia = energia
        self.curacion = curacion
        self.costeCuracion = costeCuracion
        self.experiencia = 0
        self.oro = 25
        self.xpSiguienteNivel = 150

userBase = CharacterBase('Base', 'Básico', 1,2,3,4,5)
userArcher =  Arquero("Arquero", "Oriso", 230, 79, 62, True, 1, 150, 30, 25)
#userWarrior = Guerrero("Guerrero", "Hugohin", 180, 75, 75, True, 1, 70, 25, 20)

print(userBase)
print(repr(userBase))
print(userArcher)
print(repr(userArcher))
```

Esto imprime:

```
CharacterBase(
    rol = 'Base'
    nombre = 'Básico'
    vida = 1
    ataque = 2
    defensa = 3
    vivo = True
    nivel = 5)
CharacterBase(rol='Base', nombre='Básico', vida=1, ataque=2, defensa=3, vivo=True, nivel=5)
Arquero(
    rol = 'Arquero'
    nombre = 'Oriso'
    vida = 230
    ataque = 79
    defensa = 62
    vivo = True
    nivel = 1
    energia = 150
    curacion = 30
    costeCuracion = 25
    experiencia = 0
    oro = 25
    xpSiguienteNivel = 150)
Arquero(rol='Arquero', nombre='Oriso', vida=230, ataque=79, defensa=62, vivo=True, nivel=1, energia=150, curacion=30, costeCuracion=25, experiencia=0, oro=25, xpSiguienteNivel=150)
```

Comment: Borre el comentario porque los metodos los coloque mal tabulados. Si funciono. Gracias!